# A question regarding "it"

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

If **it** is quite convenient to you, I will visit you next Monday

In the sentence, what does "**it**"(in bold) mean? Does it mean "Next Monday" or "visit next Monday"? What is the usage ot "it" here?

Comment: In a layperson's language, *'it'* applies to the entire situation of meeting the listener.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By substitution:

> If **visiting you next Monday** is quite convenient *for* you, I will visit you next Monday.

It is repetitive so we can replace the first phrase with *it*.

Also you could say:

> If **visiting you next Monday** is quite convenient *for* you, I will visit you **then**.

Comment: Thank you very much! I notice you made "for" in “If visiting you next Monday is quite convenient for you” italic. Is "to you" wrong?

Comment: You should use [***for***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/for) sense 3:"in favor of". "to" does not have such meaning afaik, and in any case it sounds wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't this be If me visiting you next Monday...

Comment: @Taemyr - No, the "me" is not required in this case. You could use something like, "If I were to visit you next Monday, would that be convenient for you?" In that wording, the pronoun is needed.